# Projectiles and motion, finding angle between position vectors

Tags: projectile-motion

Particles $P_1$ and $P_2$ have position vectors $r_1(t)=t\vec i+\frac{t^2}{2}\vec j +\vec t$ and $r_2(t)=\frac{t^2}{2}\vec i +t\vec j+t\vec k$ respectively.

Question asks us to:

> Find the angle $θ$ between the paths of these two 
>   particles at times $t = 0$ and $t → \infty$.

So the derivative of the  particle's path is the velocity of the particle so to find that:

\begin{align*}
v_1={}& 1\vec i + t\vec j + 1\vec k \\
v_2 ={}& t\vec i + 1\vec j + 1\vec k
\end{align*}

Then to find the angle I am assuming we compute the dot product:

$$v_1\cdot v_2= |v1||v2|cos θ,$$

which I then got to be:

$$\cos\theta = \dfrac{(2t+1)}{(2+t^2)},$$

and I'm not really sure where to go from here?

Comment: Put in the values of $t$ and work out the angles...

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.SE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: To ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" link rather than editing this existing question. You might have to wait a bit before you can do that, but trying to get around the wait by messing up your earlier questions puts you at increased risk of having to wait even longer. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days

Answer (score 3):

You have $\cos \theta = \frac {2t+1}{2+t^2}$.  When you take the $\arccos$ of both sides, you need to pay attention to the quadrant.  At $t=0$ this gives $\cos \theta=\frac 12$.  Look at the velocities to see whether $\theta=\frac \pi 3$ or $\frac {-\pi}3$.  As $t \to \infty$, you need to take the limit to find $\cos \theta$

Comment: so I've got θ= pi/3 and θ=pi/2 but I'm not sure i've done that correctly

Comment: @john correct (have a look at signs)